# Minecraft flying machine not going back

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to make a bamboo farm after a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEItI7AZQ0s), but I got stuck on one important thing. I can't make the flying machine go back to where it left off. If I choose according to the tutorial for the repeater to be on the 4th tick, the flying car destroys my final construction. If I let go at the first tick, it stops right in front, but does not go back. What can I do to make the machine go back?

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: It looks like you're missing the obsidian that was placed at 7:52 in the video.

Comment: In tutorial, if I'm not mistaken, it says to use any material.  Did I not understand correctly?

Comment: The tutorial says you can use any *immovable* block. If you use a movable block it won't stop the flying machine properly. Chests are immovable, so you can use one in place of the obsidian if you don't have any obsidian.

Comment: It works... i don't understand very very well english and i ommission this step... thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @LostXOR Why not turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you forgot the obsidian that was placed at [7:52](https://youtu.be/HEItI7AZQ0s?t=472) in the tutorial video. An immovable block (like obsidian, chests, droppers, etc.) is required to stop the flying machine, or it'll continue forward and break.

[image: Screen cap from video showing obsidian]

Comment: To add to the answer, in case anyone is wondering; an Immovable block cannot be pushed by a piston, or picked up by slime/honey blocks. Since the flying machine "pushes" and "pulls" itself through the air, when it reaches an Immovable block, it can no longer push any more, so when it pulls itself back, it starts moving back in the direction it came from.